# how to implement chat dialog box by programming?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-graphics

I am implementing chat application for iphone.

Please check attach image. you can see text message in brown layer with down curve arrow..I want to implement brown down curve arrow box by programming.
I have seen in lots of chat application.

[image]

So can you give me some idea about this query.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use two Bezier curves ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve ) with 
CGPathAddCurveToPoint function. Check reference for additional info: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html .